# Bootstrap Carousel mix images and iframes - not same size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, carousel

I have a carousel from bootstrap 4.4 and have 2 jpg images which all works fine, but my 3rd "image"(3D image) needs to be an iframe that links to a website where there is a 360 image.

I want this iframe to have the same height as my previous 2 carousel images and also be responsive. How can i achieve that?
My current code looks like this:

```html
<!-- Header Carousel -->
<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 nomargin">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9515_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9629_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">

            <iframe class="embed-responsive" src="https://www.kijkrond.in/stationroeselare/" alt="...">
                        </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You can define their size. or else put images and iframes in wrappers and define width and height of those wrappers. Let me know if you understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I kept searching google for an answer and i came up with something easy. Thanks to the explenation on this blog: https://blog.theodo.com/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/.

I made an empty png with the same sizes of my used pictures. Put some text in this png so i could see this was working.

I made a div where i put in the png. I gave the div a selfmade CSS class posRelative, which has overlow: hidden; and position: relative;

Then i made the iframe in the same div that has posRelative. Gave the iframe a self made css class posAbsolute which has: position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;

So my iframe is on top of the png and is scaling with it...

This works like a charm :-).

Still many thanks for the solutions given above.

```css
.posRelative{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.posAbsolute{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 nomargin">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9515_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/pictures/_MG_9629_web.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="posRelative">
                            <img src="img/pictures/Empty_web.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <iframe class="posAbsolute" src="https://www.kijkrond.in/stationroeselare/" alt="..." >
                        </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to add fixed sizes to the images. I am not advising on using bootstrap classes here because to create responsive images, because it will create responsive images but with dynamic sizes and so each image will have its own size, so it will resize itself according to its own size, even tho they will use the same class. So create a class with sizes you want to use and create media queries to make it responsive. Like this, I am using random sizes ofc.

```
.responsive-size {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .responsive-size {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .responsive-size {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:700px) {
  .responsive-size {
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
  .responsive-size {
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:300px) {
  .responsive-size {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

once the class is created, add this class to all the images and iframes that you are using like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner container">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3654088.jpg" class="d-block responsive-size img-fluid" alt="..."/>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3654088.jpg" class="d-block responsive-size img-fluid" alt="..."/>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">

                    <iframe class="embed-responsive d-block responsive-size img-fluid" src="https://www.kijkrond.in/stationroeselare/" alt="..." />
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Notice that I have removed the `w-100` class as it will mess up the sizes.